# How can I modify the Sparse Table quickly?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, sparse-matrix

**My problem is as follows:**

*For table a (MxN)
The rows of the table are numbered from 0 to M - 1, the columns of the table are numbered from 0 to N - 1. The intersection of row i and column j is called the cell (i, j). Cell (i, j) of the table contains the number of points a [i] [j] (> 0).*

**Suppose the robot is in the box (i, j). From this cell, with one move, the robot will move to the largest of the 3 cells in the column (j + 1)% N with row coordinates of (i - 1)% M, i and (i +1) % M.**

*Initially, the robot was in the box (0, 0).

There are two operations:

● `move k: tell robot to move k (1 <= k <= 10 ^ 9)`

● `change i j c: change a [i] [j] = c (0 <= i <M, 0 <= j <N, 1 <= c <= 10 ^ 9).`

*Requirements: After each movement of the robot, determine and print the new coordinates of the robot.*

input: M, N, a (MxN), Q and Q queries

**M,N,Q <= 5e3**

```
input
----------------
3 4
10 20 30 40
50 60 70 80
90 93 95 99
3
move 4
change 1 0 100
move 4
-----------------
output
-----------------
2 0
1 0
```

**MY SOLUTION O (Q*M*N*30)**

*Let nxt (i, j, k) = (u, v) be the point coordinates when starting from (i, j) after 2 ^ k steps will be in (u, v).*

The nxt function is calculated as follows:

```
for (int k = 1; k <30; k ++) {
        for (int i = 0; i <m; i ++)
            for (int j = 0; j <n; j ++) {
                nxt (i, j, k) = nxt (nxt (i, j, k-1), k-1);
            }
    }
```

So when the query is of type "move x" we only need to move it with the nxt array in no more than O (30):

now is the current position of the robot -> the position of the robot after moving x steps:

```
for (int i = 0; i <30; i ++) {
        if (x >> i & 1) {
            now = nxt (now, i);
        }
    }
```

**But the problem I encountered was the "change ijc" type query, because every time I change the value of a [i] [j] ---> c, I need to recalculate the sparse table O (M * N * 30) , so it is not effective and not feasible when Q is large.**

**I hope you can suggest a better solution, or maybe help me improve my own technique.**

**I also wonder if there is a way to edit a sparse table when an arc is changed without having to recalculate the entire table?**
In other words, it will be faster and more efficient!

**I need your help!**

**Thank you!**

Comment: How about a dirty flag for each entry? When you encounter a `change`, invalidate all entries that become invalid. And when you calculate the solution, recalculate all entries that are *dirty*? Btw, why is your matrix sparse? Looks pretty dense to me.

Comment: I agree with @NicoSchertler that the matrix doesn't seem sparse. Maybe you could provide the limits on N, M, Q, and total time this program is supposed to execute in?

Comment: I think there is a simpler solution that runs in O(QNM): perform updates by directly modifying the matrix in O(1), and for moves, perform them naively until you hit a cell that you already visited on this walk, which gives you the length of the cycle L, and then take K%L and go to the cell that was at (K%L) position in this cycle. This is O(NM) worst case if you end up visiting each cell on the walk. If O(QNM) is fast enough, I can explain this in more detail.

Comment: I understand a sparse table is a decay table, breaking down segments or intervals to be able to answer queries in good complexity for each question.
But what I am wondering is that after we create such a sparse table, whenever there is a change factor, can we modify the table quickly?

So I gave an example of it and talked about my brute force idea, and  i need your help to improve or come up with a good solution to the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: @eldar 
I want to read solution of you!

Comment: What are limits on N M and Q? Maybe there is a link to online judge with the statement?